# From MySQL table to Python list

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have this table in mysql, where I have the occurrences (CNT column) of each ITEM for each distinct ID:

```
ID     ITEM      CNT
---------------------
01     093        4
01     129F       2
01     AB56       0
01     BB44       0
01     XH7        0
01     TYE2       1
02     093        0
02     129F       3
02     AB56       1
02     BB44       0
02     XH7        2
02     TYE2       2
03     093        9
03     129F       2
03     AB56       0
03     BB44       1
03     XH7        4
03     TYE2       0
......
```

I would like to find an efficient way of importing this data from MySQL to Python so I can use them as item count vectors for a clustering procedure, in the form of a list of lists:

```
[[4,2,0,0,0,1],[0,3,1,0,2,2],[9,2,0,1,4,0]]
```

where each list represents an ID...
I'm dealing with a lot of data (millions of rows) so performance is an issue..
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
...
cursor.execute('SELECT ID, CNT FROM table_name ORDER BY ID')
item_count_vector = [
    [cnt for id_, cnt in grp]
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(cursor.fetchall(), key=lambda row: row[0])
]
```

OR (in case you use `DictCursor`-like cursor)

```
item_count_vector = [
    [d['CNT'] for d in grp]
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(cursor.fetchall(), key=lambda row: row['ID'])
]

...
```

---

```
>>> import itertools
>>> # Assume following rows are retrieved from DB using cursor.fetchall()
>>> rows = (
...     ('01',4),
...     ('01',2),
...     ('01',0),
...     ('01',0),
...     ('01',0),
...     ('01',1),
...     ('02',0),
...     ('02',3),
...     ('02',1),
...     ('02',0),
...     ('02',2),
...     ('02',2),
...     ('03',9),
...     ('03',2),
...     ('03',0),
...     ('03',1),
...     ('03',4),
...     ('03',0),
... )
>>> [[cnt for id_, cnt in grp] for key, grp in itertools.groupby(rows, key=lambda row: row[0])]
[[4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2], [9, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0]]
```

Comment: i got a keyerror:0...is it because fetch all returns it in the form of a dictionary? {'CNT': 4L, 'ID': 01L}, {'CNT': 2L, 'ID': 01L}...